# Java code for selecting and comparing cards (without Arraylist)

Tags: java

I see a lot of questions similar to this one but they are answered with code that I haven't learned yet. I am supposed to be able to do this task without an arraylist so that is providing a challenge for me. I need to play a game of war: create a card class, create a deck and then randomly generate the first card, "remove" the card from the deck and produce a 2nd card in order to see which card won, continue this comparison until the deck is exhausted. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Card
{
private int cardValue; 
private String cardSuit;
private String stringValue;
static final String[] SUIT = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"}; 
static final String[] VALUE =  {"Ace","Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}; 


/**
*CONSTRUCTOR for Card class
*contains the arrays for both suit and values
**/
public Card (int cardS, int cardV)
{

    cardSuit = SUIT[cardS]; 
    stringValue = VALUE[cardV];
}

/**
*Get method for card suit, access the value of cardSuit
**/
public String getCardSuit()
{
        return cardSuit;
}

/**
*get method for card's VALUES
**/
public String getValue()
{
    return stringValue;
}
//in order to display string value of cards
public String toString() 
{ 
    return String.format("%s of %s", stringValue, cardSuit); 
}
```

}

```
public class Deck
    {
    private final int HIGH_SUIT=3;
    private final int HIGH_VALUE=12;

    int i = 0; 
    int cardCount;              

    Card[] fullDeck = new Card[52]; 
    public Deck()
    {

        for(int s = 0; s <= HIGH_SUIT; s++)
        {
            //for loop to determine the suit
            for (int v = 0; v <= HIGH_VALUE; v++)
            {
                //construct all 52 cards and print them out 
                fullDeck[i] = new Card(s, v);
                cardCount = (i + 1);
                i++;//increment the card counter

            }
        }   
    }
```

}

```
public class War3

{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i=0;
    Deck[] fullDeck = new Deck[52]; //set up the deck
    //create a random value for the first card
    int r = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % 51);//create random number

    Card[] playerCard = new Card[r];//create the player's card

    System.out.println("The card is: " + playerCard.toString());


    }
```

As you can see, I didn't get very far with War 3 because I don't know how to display the first card. When run it displays this:The card is: [LCard;@4a5ab2random#1
How do I display the first card in the array? I need help figuring out how to assign the first card and the 2nd card, display them both then compare them. I've got a long way to go so one step at a time.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to print the `playerCard` object. By default, is using the `Object.toString()` implementation, so you should override that method in your `Card` class.

Comment: What exactly is "a game of war"? I would suggest to let the deck deal with drawing the first card.

Comment: You are initiating an array of cards instead of only one card. Replace the square brackets with normal ones to get a constructor call and remove them from the type spec like this: `Card playerCard = new Card(r)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to implement a `toString` method in your `Card` class.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s of %s", stringValue, cardSuit);
}
```

While you are at it, move the two arrays (`suit` and `value`) out of the constructor, make them `static final`, and rename to all-upper case:

```
static final String[] SUIT = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
static final String[] VALUE = {"Ace","Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
                "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
```

Also the selection of the card should not be done like you do:

```
Card[] playerCard = new Card[r];//create the player's card
```

creates an array of `r` cards, and assigns it to `playerCard`. This is incorrect: you have already created all your cards in the `Deck`, it's a matter of taking a random one from it:

```
public Card takeRandomCard() {
    int r;
    do {
        r = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
    } while (taken[r]);
    taken[r] = true;
    return fullDeck[r];
}
```

Note the little addition here: `taken` is an array of 52 `boolean` objects indicating that the card has been taken from the deck.

Here is your [code with my modifications](http://ideone.com/Myt5S) from above working at ideone.

Comment: Or make `SUIT` and `VALUE` enumerations.

Comment: @Hassan I'm not sure it that's a prudent advice: considering that they did not study ArrayLists, I think the chances that they have learned enums are somewhat slim.

Comment: It's difficult to give a simplified solution because we can't tell how much @t220 knows. In addition to dasblinkenlight's answer, look into [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I changed it but still getting the same result

Comment: @t220 Could you please update your question to show how the code looks after the update?

Comment: @t220 Take a look at the fix to the answer that I posted.

Comment: Thanks. Does this method public Card takeRandomCard() go in War3?

Comment: @t220 No, it goes in the Deck, along with the taken array.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - thanks, that works! But I am not sure how to use this method and be able to "remove" that same card from the deck. The decksize is supposed to decrease each time and make sure that same card doesn't come up again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight also...I seem to have to use this code to get a random number r = ((int) (Math.random() * 100) % decksize + 1); your code gives me the same number over and over again.?

Comment: @t220 Oh, you're right, `Math.random()` returns a double from 0, inclusive, to 1, not inclusive! You should just use `Math.random() * decksize` to get a random number from 0 to 51, inclusive. I edited the answer to reflect this change.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - this works but does it actually remove it from the deck? The assignment is to play a card then remove it from the deck thereby making the deck size smaller so you can play the game 26 turns (1 card for computer, 1 for player).

Comment: @t220 It does, absolutely! Did you figure out what for is the `taken` array?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for your help though I couldn't get it working with your code. I did get it working with other code in terms removing the cards from the deck however, I can't figure out how to compare the cards now so might have to give up on this and try with an arraylist though have to study it first.

Comment: @t220 Of course it works - I added a link to your code with my modifications at ideone; I added a loop to get 52 cards one at a time to your main, and it works as expected. I did fix a bug (added a pair of parentheses around `random()*52` part.

Answer (score 0):

Card.cardSuit and Card.stringValue are both strings for each Card object. Although you are not initializing the Cards.

You are also creating an array of 52 decks. This is unnecessary.

```
Deck[] fullDeck = new Deck[52];
```

should be

```
Deck fullDeck = new Deck();
```

you only need one deck, as the constructor for the array creates 52 card objects for you. You then want to randomly access each of these cards and display them. Thus when you have your random number r, you want to grab that number card from the `Deck` object:

```
fullDeck.fullDeck[r]
```

will retrieve a random card from your deck. To display the string values in this card:

```
System.out.println("The card is: " + fullDeck.fullDeck[r].getCardSuit() + fullDeck.fullDeck[r].getValue() + "random#" + r);
```

also declaring `new` outside of a constructor is bad form.